# AVPlayer : Fade in audio of a video

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm trying to fade-in the audio track at the start of a video using `AVPlayer`. I don't have any error when the video is played, it seems that the volume is already at 100%, and that my `volumeRamp` audio fade-in is not executed.

This is my code :

```
    guard let url = (self.videoView.player?.currentItem?.asset as? AVURLAsset)?.url else { return }

    let asset = AVAsset(url: url) as AVAsset
    let duration = asset.duration
    let durationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

    let firstSecond = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1))

    // Configure audio mix to fade in

    let audioParams = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: asset.tracks.first!)
    audioParams.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: 0, toEndVolume: 1, timeRange: firstSecond)

    let mix = AVMutableAudioMix()
    mix.inputParameters = [audioParams]
    playerItem.audioMix = mix

    self.videoView.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    self.videoView.player?.play()
```

Am I doing something wrong ? (I'm testing with simulator)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here: [Apple Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1716/_index.html)

AVAudioMix only supports file-based assets.